# Why doesn't my code to test an email address against a specific domain work?

Tags: php

I wanted to allow only specific email domain. Actually I did it. What i wanted to ask why my first code did not work at all.

I am just trying to learn PHP so that the question may seem silly, sorry for that.
Here is my code:

```
function check_email_address($email) {      
    $checkmail = print_r (explode("@",$email));
    $container = $checkmail[1];
    if(strcmp($container, "gmail.com")) {
        return true;
    }else { 
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm wondering if not it's better to use `substr()` for this, as it's only one domain to match against. I've updated my response below with the `substr()`-way of doing it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out the documentation for [`strcmp()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strcmp.php) , it will return 0 of the two strings are the same, so that's the check you want to be doing. Also, you're using [`print_r()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) when you shouldn't be, as mentioned by the other answerers.

Anyway, here's how I would have done the function - it's much simpler and uses only one line of code:

```
function check_email_address($email) {
    return (strtolower(strstr($email, '@')) == 'gmail.com');
}
```

It uses the [`strstr()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php) function and the [`strtolower()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtolower.php) function to get the domain name and change it to lower case, and then it checks if it is `gmail.com` or not. It then returns the result of that comparison.

Answer (score 2):

It's because you're using `print_r`. It doesn't do what you seem to expect from it at all. Remove it:

```
  $checkmail = explode("@", $email);
```

You can find the docs about `print_r` here:
http://php.net/print_r

Besides that, you can just use the following (it's much shorter):

```
$parts = explode("@", $email);
return (strcmp($parts[1], "gmail.com") == 0);
```

Comment: @Serge, thanks =)! I just checked and you're right. It returns zero when `$a == $b`.

Answer (score 1):

The following row doesn't work as you think it does:

```
$checkmail = print_r (explode("@",$email));
```

This means that you're trying to assign the return value from `print_r()` into `$checkmail`, but it doesn't actually return anything (if you don't supply the second, optional parameter with the value `true`).

Even then, it would've gotten a string containing the array structure, and your `$container` would have taken the value `r`, as it's the second letter in `Array`.

Bottom line: if your row would've been without the call to `print_r()`, it would've been working as planned (as long as you made sure to compare the `strcmp()` versus `0`, as it means that the strings are identical).

`Edit:`

Interesting enough, I just realized that this could be achieved with the use of `substr()` too:

```
<?php 
   //Did we find @gmail.com at the end?
   if( strtolower(substr($email, -10)) == '@gmail.com' ) {

       //Do something since it's an gmail.com-address

   } else {

       //Error handling here

   }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

No need for the print_r; explode returns a list. And in terms of style (at least, my style) no need to assign the Nth element of that list to another variable unless you intend to use it a lot elsewhere. Thus,

```
$c = explode('@',$mail);
if(strcmp($c[1],'gmail.com') == 0) return true;
return false;
```

Comment: Your strcmp is upside down. Also, there's a missing parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

You want:

```
if(strcmp($container, "gmail.com")==0)
```

instead of

```
if(strcmp($container, "gmail.com"))
```

Oh! And no inlined `print_r()` of course.

Even better:

```
return strcmp($container, "gmail.com")==0;
```